# Как вызвать функцию нужного объекта в Unity при клике на кнопку?

Tags: unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Есть три кнопки и 20 однотипных объектов.
По клику на любую из кнопок у одного из объектов должна измениться характеристика.
Вопрос в том, что я не знаю, как в инспекторе на событие OnClick повесить все объекты. А если точнее, как передать ссылку на нужный объект.
Кто понял вопрос, подскажите, как его решить )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создай в скрипте массив этих 20 объектов, добавь публичную функцию, где будешь менять характеристику определённому элементу массива:

```
public GameObject[] objects;

public void Change(){
    objects[0].Func();
}
```

Где `[0]` это индекс объекта который ты хочешь изменить, а `Func()` - функция изменения.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Но я не могу понять, какой объект добавлять в инспектор. 20 объектов создаются из скрипта на основе префаба. Но я же не могу перетащить сам префаб, как объект, из которого нужно запускать скрипт. Или могу?

Comment: Только что добавил изображение к вопросу.
Не понятно, из какого объекта вызывать функцию.

Comment: @AlAl накинь скрипт на кнопку, а в OnClick выбирай функцию Change()